# How to get the latest value from the server?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, ajax, redux

The function receives a value from the server and, if it matches, writes data to the array. In this case, the ticket.id first receives the value undefined and then the data. But the function does not have time to get the second value, and writes undefined to the array. How can you avoid this?

```
 const rules = (state) => {
    const user = state.user;
    const ticket = state.ticket;
    const relatedUsers = state.models[name].currentTicket.relatedUsers || [];
    const role = [];


    related.map(item => item.id === user.id && role.push(item.rule));

    user.Id === ticket.id ? role.push(4) : undefined;

    return role;
};
```

Comment: share full component.

Comment: Is `item.rule` defined? you do 2 push, one where you push `item.rule` and second when you push `4`.

Comment: In that case, I get different data. user.Id === ticket.id? role.push (4): undefined;

i need ticket.id to get not indefined, but when it gets last value

Answer (score 0):

You may use promise if you have asynchronous data handling to execute one after the other.

Comment: const promiseA = new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
    resolve(777);
});
promiseA.then( (val) => console.log("asynchronous logging has val:",val) );